# Why my jquery don't take that classes of this iframe?

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to get all classes whose name is "titular_portada".

There are a lot, but for some reason is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://vandal.elespanol.com" id="iframe" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("#iframe > .titulo_portada").each((i, el) => {
        console.log(el);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the main page?

Comment: Get rid of `>`. That only looks for immediate children, but there's at least `<htm>` and `<body>` elements in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");  
    var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    $(".titulo_portada",$(iframeDocument)).each((i, el) => {
        console.log(el);
    });
});
```

It should work, but jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/NickU/65dxzg3s/9/
shows errors "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin &quot;https://fiddle.jshell.net&quot; from accessing a cross-origin frame."